# Mandarin equivalent of 同 when the meaning is "for, on behalf of"

Tags: translation, grammar, mandarin, cantonese

As the dictionary entry below lists, 同 in Cantonese means `for, on behalf of`.

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/215/

In Cantonese, you might say something like this (slightly aggressive tone): 你同我企喺到! ("You stand right there!")

1) Would 和, 跟, or 给 be the right Mandarin substitute in this case?

2) What's the right substitute for 你同我畀錢! ("You pay for me!")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *1) Would 和, 跟, or 给 be the right Mandarin substitute in this case?*

- 给 in Mandarin can replace 同 in Cantonese when 同 (*for me*) denotes it is an order or demand

"你(同)我企喺度!"  = "你(給)我站著！" = "stand there (*for me*)!" (an order)

*"你(同)我企喺度" = "你(和)我站著" means "you (and) I stand there"*

*"你(同)我企喺度"= "你(跟)我站著" means "you (with) I stand there"*

- '跟/ 替' in Mandarin can replace '同' in Cantonese when '同'  means 'to, for or on behalf of'

Example:

Mandarin: "你**跟**我解釋一下" = "explain it **to** me!"

Mandarin: "你**替**我解釋一下" = "explain it **for** me!"

Cantonese: "你**同**我解釋一下" = "explain it **to**/**for** me!"

> *2) What's the right substitute for 你同我畀錢! ("You pay for me!")*

See examples above:

你**同**我畀錢 ("you pay **for** me") = "你**替**我付錢"

> If you meant "you pay!"(an order)  then you should use '給' and wrote  "你**给**我付錢!"